# Use Karma test-runner from ReSharper test

Tags: c#, jasmine, resharper, karma-runner, mstest

In our team we are using Visual Studio 2015 and for our C#-test we use MSTest and R#-test as test-runners. Both test-runners can run all our C#-test.

We also have test for javascript using Jasmine and would like to use Karma for these test. MSTest has an Karma TestAdapter, but for R# (Version 9.2) there is no support for Karma test.
R# detects the Jasmine test, but the test fails because it does not use the file references from the karma-config file.

I dont want to add all the reference files with '///

As a workaround, It would be nice if I could Disable detection for Jasmine-test in R#, but even though there is a checkmark in R#-options for "Enable Jasmine Support" it does not seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be in an almost identical scenario to yourself at the moment. I can confirm that with the Enable Jasmine support checkbox unticked R# is no longer automatically recognising them.

The change was pretty much instant when I unticked it. I can see no R# buttons down the margin, and the Unit Test Sessions frame doesn't pick up Jasmine tests.

I know that it's not particularly helpful to just disagree with what you've described, it's noteworthy that it works so in my solution though.